# Navigation Bar showing without been added

Tags: swift3, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar, xcode8

There is the Main Storyboard, from there three other storyboards with Navigation Controller, each one connected to a 4 view controllers so they use the back button to go back to their respective storyboard. 
Each Storyboard has a Storyboard reference to return to the Main Storyboard. 
Problem: each time the secondaries storyboards return to the main storyboard appears a Navigation Bar with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I used the following code in viewDidLoad():**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

and also on viewWillAppear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```